# Constructing a polynomial with boundary constraints

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, computational-mathematics

> Question:
>
> Construct a polynomial $g\left ( x \right )$ with the following properties:
>
> $g\left ( 0 \right )=\frac{3}{2}, g'\left ( 0 \right )=-4$ and $g'\left ( x \right )=0$ at $x=-1,1,2,4$
>
> Hint: $g'\left ( x \right )=\alpha \left ( x-\beta \right )\left ( x-y \right )\cdots \left ( x-\delta  \right )$

Attempt:

$g'\left ( x \right )=0 \implies \int g'\left ( x \right ).dx=C$

But $g\left ( 0 \right )=\frac{3}{2} \implies C=\frac{3}{2}$

The general idea I have is to form a differential equation by adding together the above first derivative and function and then using a software package to evaluate.

I'm not sure how the hint help. But some hints from the Mathstack community would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative function $\,g'(x)\,$ is a polynomial, and its zeros are given. Thus: 
$$ \begin{align} 
g'(x) &= \alpha\,(x+1)(x-1)(x-2)(x-4) \\[2mm] 
g'(0) &= \alpha\,(0+1)(0-1)(0-2)(0-4) =-4\quad\Rightarrow\,\alpha=\frac12 \\[2mm] 
g'(x) &= \frac{1}{2}\,(x+1)(x-1)(x-2)(x-4) \\[2mm] 
&= \frac12x^4-3x^3+\frac72x^2+3x-4
\end{align} $$ 
Hence: 
$$ g(x) =\int g'(x)\,dx = \color{red}{\frac1{10}x^5-\frac34x^4+\frac76x^3+\frac32x^2-4x+\frac32} $$ 
Where we use $\,g(0)=3/2\,$ to calculate the constant.